# Local Laravel server stops after hitting localhost once

Tags: php, laravel, server, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to develop a Laravel app locally and I'm running `php artisan serve`. It works until I visit `localhost:8000` and then the server stops. I've tried changing the port using `sudo php artisan server --port=80` but that doesn't fix it.

I haven't written a line of code yet. If it helps I'm running PHP 5.4 on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: How did you install Laravel? Did you use Composer? A Zip file? Some other way?

Comment: I installed using Composer.

Comment: And you didn't get any warnings? [Laravel requires PHP 5.6.4 or greater](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json).

Comment: I didn't get any warnings. I tried updating my version of PHP on mac to 5.6 but for some reason it's still showing 5.4.

Comment: It sounds like your PHP CLI isn't symlinked to the new installation path. Test something for me: In a separate folder, create an index.php file that contains only `<?php phpinfo(): ?>`. `cd` into that directory, and run `php -S localhost:8000`. You should be able to navigate to `localhost:8000` and see details on your PHP installation. Do you get PHP version 5.6 there? If so, what version do you see when running `php -v` in your command line? How did you install the new PHP version? Homebrew? Compiled? Something else?

Comment: Seeing 5.4.10. I used `curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`

Comment: @maiorano84 You were right! I followed the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693) and got it working! Thanks!

Comment: Great job! Feel free to post as an answer and accept it in case others have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

i think your experiencing segmentation fault(core dumped),
try running this commands

`composer dump-autoload`

`php artisan clear-compiled`

`composer clear-cache`

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have `Avast Antivirus`. This antivirus detects server.php as a threat (silently) and blocks it.

As a result, browser works good for the first request and then keeps waiting. Noting comes up on subsequent requests. Solution is to add an exception in antivirus. This problem is specific to Laravel.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Avast Antivirus, this will delete the server.php file assuming as a threat. You have to create an exception for this. Goto Avast Anitvirus -> Menu -> Settings -> General -> Exceptions. Add exception server.php file path here (add server.php file if it doesn't exist) and run the "php artisan serve" command.