# WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, Docker and Laravel launching local host won't display on browser

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a strange one here, I have been learning Laravel with Laracasts from scratch 8 for the last couple of weeks, everything in my environment (Ubuntu WSL2, Docker and Laravel 8) was running smooth all week with no issue.  I returned to work this morning and following the same boot up I always do, now any browser I use can't open the local host port that I launch from php artisan serve.

[image]

[image]

The CLI tells me that the development server is active but the browser won't connect.  I've tried changing it across different networks, dropped firewalls and cleared caches.  I've checked logs and nothing gives an indication of a problem.  Usually when I run the command `php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080&`
the ampersand keeps it alive and every refresh or connection is returned to the CLI, it's like artisan serve has stalled?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution and if somebody comes across this and can explain why it would be of great help in the future.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167414/2128089

`composer dump-autoload`
`php artisan clear-compiled`
`composer clear-cache`

This answer gave me some commands to run, which were the last I ran before a computer shutdown, once I re-ran my usual boot up I got all systems go

As expected:
[image]

I don't know if this is why it worked but it's working..